# How to extract data using BeautifulSoup with multiple conditions with multiple tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

#I want to extract description and ratings of review comments where rating is 4 or 5. Tried multiple options with latest being as below: Can someone please help

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
response = HtmlResponse(url='https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html')

url ='https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html'

r = requests.get(url) 
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
  
quotes=[]  # a list to store quotes 
   
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'reviewbox-container'})

for row in table.findAll('li', attrs = {'class':'review-box'}): 
    quote = {} 
    quote['rating'] = row.find('input', name_ = 'review.reviewRating.customer.0') 
    quote['descr'] = row.find('div',class_ = 'text_here review-desc-more') 
    print(quotes.append(quote))
```

Comment: Updated for description, this retrieves description correctly but not able to retrieve rating and then to extract selected data:------quote['descr'] = row.find('div',attrs={"class":"text_here review-desc-more"}).string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are grabbing the tag elements, when it looks like you actually want the text from the descriptions. Secondly, the `name` attribute changes for each element, so you'd either need to use regex to search for the name element that contains or starts with `review.reviewRating.customer.` Or, just simply grab the `<input>` tag, don't need to use the `name` attribute. Lastly, you don't want to `print(quotes.append(quote))` as it's going to return `None`. I think what you want to print is the actual `quote`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
response = HtmlResponse(url='https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html')

url ='https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html'

r = requests.get(url) 
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
  
quotes=[]  # a list to store quotes 
   
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'reviewbox-container'})

for row in table.findAll('li', attrs = {'class':'review-box'}): 
    quote = {} 
    if float(row.find('input')['value']) != 5.0:
        continue 
    quote['rating'] = row.find('input')['value']
    quote['descr'] = row.find('div',class_ = 'text_here review-desc-more').text.strip() 
    quotes.append(quote)
    print (quote)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer and explanation helped clear many doubts for me

Comment: @user2332713, you were nearly there. just a few minor things.

Comment: If I further want to extract from the dictionary obtained only the dscription corresponding to when rating is 5.0, I am trying below however it gives all the description values and is not filtering as expected. Can you help what I am missing: if any(d['rating'] == '5.0' for d in quotes):
    res = [d['descr'] for d in quotes]
    print(res)

Comment: Just dump it all into a dataframe and can query that. Otherwise, i can update the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot 

Answer (score 0):

Something that might really help people with this and similar issues is the option of passing a function to find() or find_all(). Pass a function that takes one element, the one to be checked, and returns True if it meets your conditions. It's really easy to get exactly what you're looking for.

Documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function